# Create Dynamically Allocated Array of Pointers C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I'm currently trying to dynamically allocate an array of character arrays and set values from another array of character arrays to the new dynamically array. When I print the values from the dynamically array I got some junk values and I can not understand where they come from.

Class -

```
class Class {

private:
    char** courses;
    int numberOfCourses;


public:
    Class();
    Class(const char** courses, int numberOfCourses);
    ~Class();

char** getCoursesList();
int getNumberOfCourses();


};
```

Constructor (allocate memory) -

```
Class:: Class(const char **courses, int numberOfCourses) {

if (numberOfCourses <= 0){
    this->numberOfCourses = 0;
    this->courses = nullptr;
} else{
    this->numberOfCourses = numberOfCourses;
    this->courses = new char*[numberOfCourses];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCourses; i++) {
        cout << strlen(courses[i]) << endl; // 5
        this->courses[i] = new char[strlen(courses[i])];
        cout << strlen(this->courses[i]) << endl; // 22
        strncpy(this->courses[i], courses[i], strlen(courses[i]));

        }
    }
}
```

getNumberOfCourses -

```
int Class::getNumberOfCourses() {
    return this->numberOfCourses;
}
```

getCoursesList -

```
char **Class::getCoursesList() {
    return this->courses;
}
```

Main -

```
const char *courses[] = {"test1", "test2", "test3" };
Class d1(courses,3);

for (int i = 0; i < d1.getNumberOfCourses(); i++) {
    cout << d1.getCoursesList()[i] << endl;
}
```

Output -

> [test1═²²²²▌▌▌▌▌▌l┴╓K▌] [test2═²²²²▌▌▌▌▌▌@┴2K▌] [test3═²²²²▌▌▌▌▌▌Y┴;K▌]

I would love to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mcve]. What is `Class`? What does `Class::getCoursesList()` do and return?

Comment: A hint though: The string ***null-terminator*** is not counted with the `strlen` function, and not included in your `strncpy` call. Allocate space for it, and use `strcpy`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Question has been updated

Comment: @SaiSreenivas I call explicitly to the constructor, " Class d1(courses,3); "

Comment: Another hint: Unless using `new[]` and null-terminated byte strings is mandated by your assignment or exercise, use `std::vector` and `std::string`. Will make your life as a C++ programmer *so* much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Look here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) as you may understand from the documentation, strlen function does not count `\0` character which is end of the string. Hence it is not copied with strcpy function call, and cout does not encounter with `\0`. This is the reason of absurd characters in terminal output. While allocating memory for course names, allocate for one more char and add `\0` end of the char array.

Comment: I try to add 1 to the len and add '\0' and still got to same junk values.


this->courses[i] = new char[strlen(courses[i]) + 1];
this->courses[strlen(courses[i])] = '\0';

Comment: @0xAlon If you use `strcpy` instead of `strncpy` you don't have to explicitly add the terminator (you must still allocate memory for it though).